# Which is better for list View in getView(), Inflating view or Creating View by coding

Tags: android, listview

I have one question for list view. At the time of creating list item in getView() method, which is a good option for list view. Creating views through coding or inflating view through xml. I am thinking about memory utilization & performance of list view.

Normally list item contain one product image with their name & 3 line description. Means one Image View & two text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `Views` through code is usually not recommended and is justified only in cases when you can't deal without it. Using XML is always best practice so you should use this approach no matter where you're using your `Views`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Egor for replying, But for Image I have one question. I get image from server, and for this I start AsynTask for every Image. when Image get from asyntask I set this to image view. For this I pass ImageView to AsynTask. But when Image is set by AsynTask then that time UI get hanged or stop for sec. And which effect during scrolling, which scroll with this disturbance, can you give any suggestion or example for this.

Comment: @AmolWadekar, You may take a look at this set of posts: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html. This is the best resource on populating ListViews with Bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recycle views. Are you using a VieHolder?. My suggestion is use a view holder inflate using xml. ViewHolder will increase performance of ListView.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. Check this link.

Comment: +1, Yes. Making use of already created excits will increase performance

Comment: Thank You Raghunandan k & Raghu for reply. I use the ViewHolder for performance. But using ViewHolder I face one problem for Image. When image is reused then it is display previous image, which is replace later when their thread is finished. But displaying wrong image firstly & then original is not looking good. Is any suggestion for this from your end.

Comment: Cano you post the code. Are you  displaying image based on position in getview().